# C++/XCode - Binding value of type 'const double' to reference to type 'double' drops 'const' qualifier

Tags: c++, xcode

I've implemented a node class and a sequence class as template classes. They worked fine with my test program, but when I try to use the test program I was provided with, I get this error.

**Binding value of type 'const double' to reference to type 'double' drops 'const' qualifier**

The error points to a few different places in my code:

In main.cpp, it points to the if statement below:

```
if (*itr != i)
        {
            // Our iterators have not ended with us on the correct value.
            cout << "\nIncorrect value found.\n";
            cout << "Expected: " << i << ". Found: " << *itr << "." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
```

In node2.h it points to the return statement below:

```
Item& operator *( ) 
    { return current->data( ); }
```

I've included my node2.h and node2.cxx. I'm not 100% sure what this error means and how it applies to my program. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

node2.h:

```
#ifndef COEN_79_NODE_H
#define COEN_79_NODE_H
#include <cstdlib> // Provides size_t and NULL
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>


namespace coen79_lab8
{
    template <class Item>
    class node
    {
    public:
        // TYPEDEF
        typedef Item value_type;

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        node(const Item& init_data = Item( ), node* init_link = NULL)
        {
            data_field = init_data;
            link_field = init_link;
        }

        // Member functions to set the data and link fields:
        void set_data(const Item& new_data) { data_field = new_data; }
        void set_link(node* new_link) { link_field = new_link; }

        // Constant member function to retrieve the current data:
        const Item& data( ) const { return data_field; }

        // Two slightly different member functions to retreive
        // the current link:
        const node* link( ) const { return link_field; }
        node* link( ) { return link_field; }

    private:
        Item data_field;
        node* link_field;
    };

    // FUNCTIONS for the linked list toolkit
    template <class Item>
    size_t list_length(const node<Item>* head_ptr);

    template <class Item>
    void list_head_insert(node<Item>*& head_ptr, const Item& entry);

    template <class Item>
    void list_insert(node<Item>* previous_ptr, const Item& entry);

    template <class NodePtr, class Item>
    NodePtr list_search(NodePtr head_ptr, const Item& target);

    template <class NodePtr, class SizeType>
    NodePtr list_locate(NodePtr head_ptr, SizeType position);

    template <class Item>
    void list_head_remove(node<Item>*& head_ptr);

    template <class Item>
    void list_remove(node<Item>* previous_ptr);

    template <class Item>
    void list_clear(node<Item>*& head_ptr);

    template <class Item>
    void list_copy(const node<Item>* source_ptr, node<Item>*& head_ptr, node<Item>*& tail_ptr);
    // YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THE FOLLOWING FUNCTIONS

    template <class NodePtr, class Item>
    void list_piece(NodePtr start_ptr, NodePtr end_ptr, node<Item>*& head_ptr, node<Item>*& tail_ptr);

    template <class Item>
    size_t list_occurrences(node<Item>* head_ptr, const Item& target);

    template <class Item>
    void list_insert_at(node<Item>*& head_ptr, const Item& entry, size_t position);

    template <class Item>
    Item list_remove_at(node<Item>*& head_ptr, size_t position);

    template <class NodePtr, class Item>
    NodePtr list_copy_segment(node<Item>* head_ptr, size_t start, size_t finish);

// FORWARD ITERATORS to step through the nodes of a linked list
// A node_iterator of can change the underlying linked list through the
// * operator, so it may not be used with a const node. The
// node_const_iterator cannot change the underlying linked list
// through the * operator, so it may be used with a const node.
// WARNING:
// This classes use std::iterator as its base class;
// Older compilers that do not support the std::iterator class can
// delete everything after the word iterator in the second line:


//You need to change these to template classes and implement the functions for these classes

template <class Item>
class node_iterator
: public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, Item>
{
public:
    node_iterator(node<Item>* initial = NULL)
    { current = initial; }
    Item& operator *( ) 
    { return current->data( ); }
    node_iterator& operator ++( )
    {
        current = current->link( );
        return *this;
    }
    node_iterator operator ++(int)
    {
        node_iterator original(current);
        current = current->link( );
        return original;
    }
    bool operator ==(const node_iterator other) const
    { return current == other.current; }
    bool operator !=(const node_iterator other) const
    { return current != other.current; }
private:
    node<Item>* current;
};

template <class Item>
class const_node_iterator
: public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, const Item>
{
public:
    const_node_iterator(const node<Item>* initial = NULL)
    { current = initial; }
    const Item& operator *( ) const
    { return current->data( ); }
    const_node_iterator& operator ++( )
    {
        current = current->link( );
        return *this;
    }
    const_node_iterator operator ++(int) 
    {
        const_node_iterator original(current);
        current = current->link( );
        return original;
    }
    bool operator ==(const const_node_iterator other) const
    { return current == other.current; }
    bool operator !=(const const_node_iterator other) const
    { return current != other.current; }

    private:
        const node<Item>* current;
    };
}
#include "node2.cxx"
#endif
```

node2.cxx:

```
// FILE: node.cxx
// IMPLEMENTS: The functions of the node class and the
// linked list toolkit (see node2.h for documentation).
// INVARIANT for the node class:
//   The data of a node is stored in data_field
//   and the link to the next node is stored in link_field.

#include <cassert>    // Provides assert
#include <cstdlib>    // Provides NULL and size_t

namespace coen79_lab8
{
    template <class Item>
    size_t list_length(const node<Item>* head_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        const node <Item> *cursor;
        size_t answer;

        answer = 0;
        for (cursor = head_ptr; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->link( ))
            ++answer;

        return answer;
    }

    template <class Item>
    void list_head_insert(node<Item>*& head_ptr, const Item& entry)
    {
        head_ptr = new node<Item>(entry, head_ptr);
    }

    template <class Item>
    void list_insert(node<Item>* previous_ptr, const Item& entry)
    {
        node<Item> *insert_ptr;

        insert_ptr = new node<Item>(entry, previous_ptr->link( ));
        previous_ptr->set_link(insert_ptr);
    }

    template <class NodePtr, class Item>
    NodePtr list_search(NodePtr head_ptr, const Item& target)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        NodePtr cursor;

        for (cursor = head_ptr; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->link( ))
            if (target == cursor->data( ))
                return cursor;
        return NULL;
    }

    template <class NodePtr, class SizeType>
    NodePtr list_locate(NodePtr head_ptr, SizeType position)
    // Library facilities used: cassert, cstdlib
    {
        NodePtr cursor;
        SizeType i;

        assert(0 < position);
        cursor = head_ptr;
        for (i = 1; (i < position) && (cursor != NULL); ++i)
            cursor = cursor->link( );
        return cursor;
    }

    template <class Item>
    void list_head_remove(node<Item>*& head_ptr)
    {
        node<Item> *remove_ptr;

        remove_ptr = head_ptr;
        head_ptr = head_ptr->link( );
        delete remove_ptr;
    }

    template <class Item>
    void list_remove(node<Item>* previous_ptr)
    {
        node<Item> *remove_ptr;

        remove_ptr = previous_ptr->link( );
        previous_ptr->set_link(remove_ptr->link( ));
        delete remove_ptr;
    }

    template <class Item>
    void list_clear(node<Item>*& head_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        while (head_ptr != NULL)
            list_head_remove(head_ptr);
    }

    template <class Item>
    void list_copy(const node<Item>* source_ptr, node<Item>*& head_ptr, node<Item>*& tail_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        head_ptr = NULL;
        tail_ptr = NULL;

        // Handle the case of the empty list
        if (source_ptr == NULL)
            return;

        // Make the head node for the newly created list, and put data in it
        list_head_insert(head_ptr, source_ptr->data( ));
        tail_ptr = head_ptr;

        // Copy rest of the nodes one at a time, adding at the tail of new list
        source_ptr = source_ptr->link( );
        while (source_ptr != NULL)
        {
            list_insert(tail_ptr, source_ptr->data( ));
            tail_ptr = tail_ptr->link( );
            source_ptr = source_ptr->link( );
        }
    }

    template <class NodePtr, class Item>
    void list_piece(const NodePtr start_ptr, const NodePtr end_ptr, node<Item>*& head_ptr, node<Item>*& tail_ptr)
    {
        head_ptr = NULL;
        tail_ptr = NULL;
        // Handle the case of the empty list.
        if (start_ptr == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        // Make the head node for the newly created list, and put data in it.
        list_head_insert(head_ptr, start_ptr->data( ));
        tail_ptr = head_ptr;
        // Copy the rest of the nodes one at a time, adding at the tail of new list.
        start_ptr = start_ptr->link( );
        while (start_ptr != end_ptr)
        {
            list_insert(tail_ptr, start_ptr->data( ));
            tail_ptr = tail_ptr->link( );
            start_ptr = start_ptr->link( );
        }
        return;
    }

    template <class Item>
    size_t list_occurrences(node<Item>* head_ptr, const Item& target)
    {
        size_t answer = 0;

        for (head_ptr = list_search(head_ptr, target);
             head_ptr != NULL;
             head_ptr = list_search(head_ptr->link(), target))
        answer++;

        return answer;
    }

    template <class Item>
    void list_insert_at(node<Item>*& head_ptr, const Item& entry, size_t position)
    {
        assert(position > 0);
        node<Item> *precursor;

        if (position == 1)
           list_head_insert(head_ptr, entry);
        else
        {
            precursor = list_locate(head_ptr, position-1);
            assert(precursor != NULL);
            list_insert(precursor, entry);
        }
    }

    template <class Item>
    Item list_remove_at(node<Item>*& head_ptr, size_t position)
    {
        assert(position > 0);
        node<Item> *precursor;
        Item answer;

        if (position == 1)
        {
            assert(head_ptr != NULL);
            answer = head_ptr->data();
            list_head_remove(head_ptr);
        }
        else
        {
            precursor = list_locate(head_ptr, position-1);
            assert(precursor != NULL);
            assert(precursor->link() != NULL);
            answer = precursor->link()->data();
            list_remove(precursor);
        }
        return answer;
    }

    template <class NodePtr, class Item>
    NodePtr list_copy_segment(node<Item>* head_ptr, size_t start, size_t finish)
    {
        node<Item> *start_ptr;
        node<Item> *finish_ptr;
        node<Item> *new_head;
        node<Item> *new_tail;

        assert((1 <= start) && (start <= finish) && (finish <= list_length(head_ptr)));
        ++finish;


        start_ptr = list_locate(head_ptr, start);
        assert(start_ptr != NULL);
        finish_ptr = list_locate(start_ptr, finish-start+1);
        list_piece(start_ptr, finish_ptr, new_head, new_tail);
        return new_head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make an overload for that operator: `Item operator *( ) const { return current->data( ); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key line is this one:

```
const Item& data( ) const { return data_field; }
```

Here you declare that the data() method returns a const reference to an Item. Since you are returning a reference, you are not copying the Item, you are giving access to the variable data_field. Normally, if you have access to this data, you can modify it. However, you declared the reference to be const reference, which means you forbid it to be modified.

This is fine so far, but then you have this:

```
Item& operator *( ) 
    { return current->data( ); }
```

This returns a normal reference, not a const reference, which means you are saying it can be modified. But current->data() returns a const&, so this is "dropping the const qualifier", you are breaking the promise that you made when you declared data() to return a const&.

There are a few possible solutions:

1. Have data() return a reference instead of a const& (just delete the const)
2. Declare operator*() to return a const Item& instead of an Item&
3. Change

   ```
   Item& operator *( ) 
       { return current->data( ); }
   ```

   into

   ```
   Item& operator *( ) 
      { return const_cast<Item&>(current->data( )); }
   ```

This will tell the compiler that you are dropping the const qualifier on purpose, and not to complain